# Add constraints for Redis value

Tags: redis, constraints

I'd like to set constraints for Redis value, here are some of the scenarios:

1) number range constraint:

- `DECR product007_stocks`, if the value_of(product007_stocks) less than 0, then the `DECR` operation fail
- `LPUSH user_ages 20`, if the value is less than 18, then the `LPUSH` operation fail

2) set/list size constraint:

- `LPUSH first_500_users userid_007`, if the list size is over 500, then the `LPUSH` operation fail

And some others constraints just like RMDB.

Does Redis already support this and I just did not find the document? or they are not supported yet, does Redis have the plan to support it?

Thanks.

Comment: You could add that functionality via `Lua` if you really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis does not enforce such constraints. As noted by Mark in the comments, the usual way to go about this is implemented Lua scripts that enforce the logic. OTOH, and again as Mark pointed out, you should not think of Redis as an RDBMS because it isn't, so be judicious about what you're trying to do.